# Не пойму проблему с кодировкой скрипта Python3

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, кодировка, utf-8

(Я начинающий программист-самоучка)

Написал программу на python3, содержащую кирилицу в str и в блоках комментарии. Приведу пример участка кода, дабы было ясно о чем имею ввиду:

```
print('Загрузка...')
try:
    f = open('bufer.txt', 'r')  # Читаем буфер
except FileNotFoundError:
print('Файл с базой данных в директории программы не найден')
```

Программа(и ее копии) долгое время отлично работала в различных системах Windows, Linux, как в различных IDE так и напрямую. После того как копия скрипта была скопирована на удаленный сервер (Ubuntu) и с него запущена - отобразило ошибку кодировки:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "1.py", line 28, in 
>       print('****************<<<   \u041c\u043e\u0434\u0443\u043b\u044c AstroVK v1   >>>****************')
>   UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 22-27: ordinal not in range(128)

28 строчка у меня такая:

```
28.    print('****************<<<   Модуль AstroVK v1   >>>****************')
```

Не могу понять в чем дело, ведь кодировка задана в начале файла UTF-8

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: убедитесь, что файл действительно сохранен в utf8 без BOM. попробуйте добавить к строкам префикс 'u' `print(u'здесь текст')`

Comment: Кодировка в консоли удаленного сервера поддерживает кириллицу?

Comment: решено. причина была именно в кодировке консоли сервера